# Fluent Nhibernate save child.parentid = parentId on new parent & Child

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to save a new parent item & new child item to a legacy database

I get my data just fine, when I save it saves both the parent and the child.  however the Child's SillyNameParentId is always 0

The table structure I can't change so I have to figure out how to make this work.

Here is the SQL generated

> NHibernate: INSERT INTO SillyNameParent(Description, Active) VALUES
>   (@p0, @p1); select     SCOPE_IDENTITY();@p0 = 'Test' [Type: String
>   (1073741823)], @p1 = True [Type: Boolean (0)] NHibernate: INSERT INTO
>   SillyChild (SillyNameCategoryId, sillyNameParentid) VALUES (@p0, @p1);
>   select SCOPE_IDENTITY();@p0 = 0 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p1 = 1 [Type:
>   Int32 (0)]

Ultimately I want @p1 to be set as SillyNameParentId/Parentid

Tables:

```
SillyNameParent
    Column PK-IsIdentity: ParentId
    Column varchar(255): Description
    Column bit: Active

SillyChild //I'm a lookup table 
    Column int IsIdentity: Id
    Column int PK: SillyNameParentId
    Column int PK: SillyNameCategoryID
```

MODELS:

```
public class SillyNameParent: Entity
{
    public SillyNameParent()
    {
        Children= new List<SillyChild>();
    }
    public virtual string AreaOfConcernDesc { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Active { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<SillyChild> Children{ get; set; }
}

public class SillyChild: Entity
{
    public virtual int SillyNameParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual int SillyNameCategoryId{ get; set; }
    public virtual SillyNameParent Parent { get; set; }

}
```

MAPS:

```
public class SillyNameParentMap : IAutoMappingOverride<SillyNameParent>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<SillyNameParent> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Table("SillyNameParent");
        mapping.Id(x => x.Id).Column("ParentId").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        mapping.Map(x => x.Description).Not.Nullable();
        mapping.Map(x => x.Active).Nullable();
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.children)
            .Cascade.All()
            .KeyColumn("SillyNameParentId")
            .Not
            .LazyLoad();
    }
}

public class SillyChildMap: IAutoMappingOverride<SillyChild>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<SillyChild> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Table("SillyChild");
        mapping.Id(x => x.Id).Column("Id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        mapping.Map(x => x.SillyNameParentId).Not.Nullable();
        mapping.Map(x => x.SillyNameCategoryId).Not.Nullable();
        mapping.HasOne(x => x.Parent).ForeignKey("SillyNameParentId");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a work around...  Because the identity is being set by the DB I'm guessing I need to save the parent before saving the children.  There has got to be a better way however here is what I came up with

```
 public T SaveReturnEntity(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Session.Save(entity);
        }
        catch
        {
            if (this.Session.IsOpen)
            {
                this.Session.Close();
            }

            throw;
        }

        this.Session.Flush();
        return entity;
    }



 return _sillyParent.SaveReturnEntity(sillyNameParent) != null;


 [Test]
    public void Save_sillyParent()
    {
        var sillyService = ServiceMiniMart.CreateSillyParent();

        var filter = new sillyQueryFilter();
        {
            CategoryId = 1
        };      
        var snp= new SillyNameParent
            {
                Active = true,
                Description= "Test"
            };
        if (sillyService.SaveSillyParent(snp))
        {
           snp.Category = new List<SillyChild>
               {
                   new SillyChild
                       {
                           SillyNameParentId= snp.Id,
                           SillyNameCategoryId= filter.CategoryId.Value,
                           Parent = snp
                       }
               };
        }


       var a =  sillyService.SaveSillyParent(snp);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would say, you are almost there. Just the mapping parent/child should be like this:

SillyNameParentMap:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<SillyNameParent> mapping)
{
    ...
    mapping.HasMany(x => x.Children)
        .Cascade.All()
        .KeyColumn("SillyNameParentId")
        .Inverse() // this is the way how to manage insertions
        .Not
        .LazyLoad();
```

SillyChildMap:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<SillyChild> mapping)
{
    ...
    mapping.References(x => x.Parent)
       .Column("SillyNameParentId");
```

This mapping would end up in correct insertion, just do it like this:

```
var parent = new SillyNameParent();
parent... // set properties

var child = new SillyChild();
child... // set properties

parent.Children.Add(child); // parent knows about child
child.Parent = parent; // always do set the relation both ways

sillyService.SaveSillyParent(snp)
```

EDIT: the select 2 issue

What the exception says, is the doubled column mapping. It is an issue in case of INSERT or UPDATE. But with NHibernate we can solve it easily:

```
mapping.Map(x => x.SillyNameParentId)
    .Not.Nullable()
    .Not.Insert()
    .Not.Update();
mapping.References(x => x.Parent)
    .Column("SillyNameParentId");
```

So, now we have both properties mapped (the reference Parent and its int representation). Only the reference will be used for INSERT, UPDATE. But both could be used for Select, Filter/Where and Order by...

Comment: I've actually tried that with out success,  When the sillyChild  uses mapping.Refrences I get this error:Erro dehydrating property value for ...Parent ,InnerException:Invalid index 2 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=2.

Comment: I cannot see the error? is it part of your comment? The parent child relationship is very usual. the most usual. and it does work without "workaround". Please, give some more information .. we will find solution. Wow... I see. I will come back during an hour... and take a look

Comment: Yes I agree it's a very common relationship and I use that pattern quite a bit.  however I was thinking because this DB is legacy and the parent table ID columns are named differently than the child look up table columns that reference the parent name columns, coupled with the DB setting the identity may be the reason why the pattern is not working.  Thanks for the post and thanks in advance for looking into it further

Comment: I've updated my answer. To solve the issue we only have to assure, that each column is mapped only once for purposes of INSERT and UPDATE. Now we should have all the standard stuff. BTW this way I use very often... very handy ;)